# Rename a multilevel dateTime Index Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that look like this

```
                     Sale    Purchase
date date date date  100       3
2018  2    1    1    200       6 
2018  1    2    3    150       8
2017  12   1    1    100       1
2017  11   2    2    50        2
```

Instead, I'm hoping it could be

```
                           Sale    Purchase
Year Month Week Dayofweek  100       3
2018  2    1    1          200       6 
2018  1    2    3          150       8
2017  12   1    1          100       1
2017  11   2    2          50        2
```

I have tried `df_monthly.MultiIndex.rename("Year","Month","Week","Dayofweek")`
but I get the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'MultiIndex'. Is there another way to rename these indexes? Thanks

I also tried df_monthly=pd.MultiIndex.rename(df_monthly.index,['Year','Month','Week','Day of week'],[0,1,2,3]) which don't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many search and trial and error, the solution is as follows

```
df_monthly.index.names=['Year','Month','Week','Day of Week']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
df_monthly.index.set_names('Year', level=0)
```

or

```
df_monthly.index.set_names(('Year','Month', 'Week', 'Dayofweek'))
```

as you can deduce from the error, df.index attribute stores an instance of the class MultiIndex.

Comment: Hi, I tried both and both methods don't work. The indexes stayed the same. Thanks for helping!

Comment: please use `inplace=True` if you don't want a copy. Please read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.set_names.html)